# Upload image to Facebook from email

Tags: php, facebook, image, email, facebook-graph-api

I have set up code that generates images from a user's stats on my website and displays it embedded in an email sent to them. I would like to add the option for people to upload this image to Facebook, but I am having issues with understanding the best way to do this (if there is one).

My code uses the PHP GD image library to pull stats, create the image, and save the file to the server. I also set up a cron job to empty the image folder daily as I intend for the images to exist only when they need to be viewed, as opening the email will create the image again.

I realize that I can send the image generated by PHP to the Facebook sharer url below.

```
http://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://example.com/image.png
```

The issue I am running into is that this shares the image url, rather than uploading the image itself to Facebook. As the server is wiped daily, the url does not exist consistently and would be inaccessible one day after it is shared.

I see that there are options such as using the [Graph API via a url](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/), but I'm unsure if this can be set up through email alone. My email client appears to only allow the use of HTML so I am limited in the options I can use. It also seems to require user permissions which is a lot to ask someone to upload a single image.

What is the best way to allow users to upload images from their email to Facebook for sharing purposes?

Comment: If you just want users to be able to share without having to login to your app and give it additional permissions, then the easiest way to do with would be to let them share links, that embed the image via Open Graph meta tags. This can all be dynamic – a script that outputs the OG meta data, according to a GET parameter passed to it, and the image creation as well (as long as the same image URL always returns the appropriate image, it doesn’t matter whether is it saved on the server, or created on-the-fly each time.)

Comment: The image is generated with a random url from the email, so there's no way to tell what it will be beforehand. I can send the created image to a script to generate OG meta and use that for the initial facebook upload, but won't the image not work anymore once it's deleted? For example, if they were to go back the next day that image used would no longer have a url that points to anything. Does Facebook cache og images to prevent this from occurring or does it take the image and upload it so that it will always appear the same regardless of whether it still exists?

Comment: At some point you must create the image URL, no? Emails don’t magically alter their content by themselves. And what does it matter if it is deleted - as you said, viewing it in the mail creates it again, no? // Facebook does create a copy of the image on their own CDN; but they will re-scrape every object regularly, and if your image is “missing” when that happens, there’s no telling ow FB handles that.

Comment: Well yes, that's the problem that I've been describing. The image URL is created until the next day, at which point it would be deleted to free up space. If someone were to share the image from the email it would work as the image is available at that time, but they will most likely not view the email every day to generate the same URL again while the image is live on Facebook from that point forward. So Facebook would be pointing to a dead link most of the time... it seems like the only way to do this is to upload the image directly to Facebook rather than sharing a url at all.

Comment: As long as you have all the data to create that particular image in the image URL, you can re-recreate it at any time. And it doesn't even have to be stored, just creating the image on-the-fly and outputting the raw image data would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the correct way to upload photos to a Profile: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#Creating

Of course you need to authorize the user with `publish_actions` for this.

Comment: Is it possible to use this without knowing the user_id of the profile?

Comment: not sure what you mean, you MUST authorize the user with publish_actions for this. the user id is irrelevant, you can use the /me/photos endpoint to post photos. but you can easily get the user id after authorization anyway, if you want it.

Comment: Alright, so I see that the URL I need to use for my http request would look something like: https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?url=URL&access_token=TOKEN. How would I set up the POST request, is it possible to send this through the url?

Comment: you can use php curl for it. use the javascript sdk for login and getting the access token. for example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I needed to do this all through email so JS might be out. It seems that I could try inserting a form with a POST request.

Comment: well, you do have to build a login process. there is no way to just present a link or form in an email for this. the user must be logged in (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login) and must have authorized the publish_actions permission. after that, you can do a post request to upload the photo.